# jQuery store locator - removing the google map and its functionality

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have a store locator which works just fine however i want to remove the map functionality so i can just use the geolocation service, run through json file and find the closest store - everything is there i just need some help stripping out the maps / marker stuff

Would someone be able to help with this? the code starts at: //Create the map with jQuery

im assuming most can be removed but the loop needs to be kept for the list data (i only want to show 1 being the closest not a list though)

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.storeLocator = function (options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            'mapDiv': 'map',
            'listDiv': 'list',
            'formID': 'user-location',
            'inputID': 'address',
            'zoomLevel': 12,
            'pinColor': 'fe7569',
            'pinTextColor': '000000',
            'storeLimit': 26,
            'distanceAlert': 60,
            'dataLocation': 'locations.xml',
            'listColor1': 'ffffff',
            'listColor2': 'eeeeee',
            'bounceMarker': true,
            'slideMap': true,
            'modalWindow': false,
            'defaultLoc': false,
            'defaultLat': '',
            'defaultLng': '',
            'jsonData': false,
            'autoGeocode': false
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {

            var $this = $(this);

            //Add modal window divs if set
            if (settings.modalWindow == true) {
                $this.wrap('<div id="overlay"><div id="modal-window"><div id="modal-content">');
                $('#modal-window').prepend('<div id="close-icon"><\/div>');
                $('#overlay').hide();
            }

            if (settings.slideMap == true) {
                //Let's hide the map container to begin
                $this.hide();
            }

            var userinput, olat, olng, marker, letter, storenum;
            var locationset = new Array();

            //Calculate geocode distance functions - you could use Google's distance service instead
            var GeoCodeCalc = {};
            GeoCodeCalc.EarthRadiusInMiles = 3956.0;
            GeoCodeCalc.EarthRadiusInKilometers = 6367.0;
            GeoCodeCalc.ToRadian = function (v) { return v * (Math.PI / 180); };
            GeoCodeCalc.DiffRadian = function (v1, v2) {
                return GeoCodeCalc.ToRadian(v2) - GeoCodeCalc.ToRadian(v1);
            };
            GeoCodeCalc.CalcDistance = function (lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, radius) {
                return radius * 2 * Math.asin(Math.min(1, Math.sqrt((Math.pow(Math.sin((GeoCodeCalc.DiffRadian(lat1, lat2)) / 2.0), 2.0) + Math.cos(GeoCodeCalc.ToRadian(lat1)) * Math.cos(GeoCodeCalc.ToRadian(lat2)) * Math.pow(Math.sin((GeoCodeCalc.DiffRadian(lng1, lng2)) / 2.0), 2.0)))));
            };

            //Geocode function for the origin location
            function GoogleGeocode() {
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                this.geocode = function (address, callbackFunction) {
                    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var result = {};
                            result.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                            result.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                            callbackFunction(result);
                        } else {
                            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                            callbackFunction(null);
                        }
                    });
                };
            }

            //Reverse geocode to get address for automatic options needed for directions link
            function ReverseGoogleGeocode() {
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                this.geocode = function (latlng, callbackFunction) {
                    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (results[0]) {
                                var result = {};
                                result.address = results[0].formatted_address;
                                callbackFunction(result);
                            }
                        } else {
                            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                            callbackFunction(null);
                        }
                    });
                };
            }

            //If a default location is set
            if (settings.defaultLoc == true) {
                //The address needs to be determined for the directions link
                var r = new ReverseGoogleGeocode();
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(settings.defaultLat, settings.defaultLng);
                r.geocode(latlng, function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        var originAddress = data.address;
                        mapping(settings.defaultLat, settings.defaultLng, originAddress);
                    } else {
                        //Unable to geocode
                        alert('Unable to find address');
                    }
                });
            }

            //HTML5 geolocation API option
            if (settings.autoGeocode == true) {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(autoGeocode_query, autoGeocode_error);
                }
            }

            //If location is detected automatically
            function autoGeocode_query(position) {
                //The address needs to be determined for the directions link
                var r = new ReverseGoogleGeocode();
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                r.geocode(latlng, function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        var originAddress = data.address;
                        mapping(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, originAddress);
                    } else {
                        //Unable to geocode
                        alert('Unable to find address');
                    }
                });
            }

            function autoGeocode_error(error) {
                //If automatic detection doesn't work show an error
                alert("Automatic location detection failed. Please fill in your address or zip code.");
            }

            //Used to round miles to display
            function roundNumber(num, dec) {
                var result = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec);
                return result;
            }

            //Process form input
            $(function () {
                $(document).on('submit', '#' + settings.formID, function (e) {
                    //Stop the form submission
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //Get the user input and use it
                    var userinput = $('#' + settings.formID + ' #' + settings.inputID).val();

                    if (userinput == "") {
                        //Show alert and stop processing
                        alert("The input box was blank.");
                    }
                    else {
                        var g = new GoogleGeocode();
                        var address = userinput;
                        g.geocode(address, function (data) {
                            if (data != null) {
                                olat = data.latitude;
                                olng = data.longitude;
                                mapping(olat, olng, userinput);
                            } else {
                                //Unable to geocode
                                alert('ERROR! Unable to geocode address');
                            }
                        });
                    }

                });
            });


            //Now all the mapping stuff
            function mapping(orig_lat, orig_lng, origin) {
                $(function () {

                    var dataType;

                    //JSON or XML?
                    if (settings.jsonData == true) { dataType = "json"; }
                    else { dataType = "xml"; }

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: settings.dataLocation,
                        dataType: dataType,
                        success: function (data) {

                            //After the store locations file has been read successfully
                            var i = 0;

                            //Depending on your data strucutre and what you want to include in the maps, you may need to change the following variables or comment them out
                            if (settings.jsonData == true) {
                                //Process JSON
                                $.each(data, function () {

                                    var name = this.locname;
                                    var lat = this.lat;
                                    var lng = this.lng;

                                    var distance = GeoCodeCalc.CalcDistance(orig_lat, orig_lng, lat, lng, GeoCodeCalc.EarthRadiusInMiles);

                                    //Create the array
                                    locationset[i] = new Array(distance, name, lat, lng);

                                    i++;
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                //Process XML
                                $(data).find('marker').each(function () {
                                    //Take the lat lng from the user, geocoded above
                                    var name = $(this).attr('name');
                                    var lat = $(this).attr('lat');
                                    var lng = $(this).attr('lng');

                                    var distance = GeoCodeCalc.CalcDistance(orig_lat, orig_lng, lat, lng, GeoCodeCalc.EarthRadiusInMiles);

                                    //Create the array
                                    locationset[i] = new Array(distance, name, lat, lng);

                                    i++;
                                });
                            }

                            //Sort the multi-dimensional array numerically
                            locationset.sort(function (a, b) {
                                var x = a[0];
                                var y = b[0];
                                return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
                            });

                            //Check the closest marker
                            if (locationset[0][0] > settings.distanceAlert) {
                                alert("Unfortunately, our closest location is more than " + settings.distanceAlert + " miles away.");
                            }

                            //Create the map with jQuery
                            $(function () {

                                var storeDistance, storeName;

                                //Instead of repeating the same thing twice below
                                function create_store_variables(loopcount) {
                                    storeDistance = locationset[loopcount][0];
                                    storeName = locationset[loopcount][1];

                                    storeDistance = roundNumber(storeDistance, 2);
                                }

                                //Google maps settings
                                var myOptions = {
                                    zoom: settings.zoomLevel,
                                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(orig_lat, orig_lng),
                                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                };

                                if (settings.slideMap == true) {
                                    //Slide in the map container
                                    $this.slideDown();
                                }

                                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(settings.mapDiv), myOptions);
                                var markers = new Array();
                                //Create one infowindow to fill later
                                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                                //Avoid error if number of locations is less than the default of 26
                                if ((locationset.length - 1) < settings.storeLimit - 1) {
                                    storenum = locationset.length - 1;
                                }
                                else {
                                    storenum = settings.storeLimit - 1;
                                }

                                //Add markers and infowindows loop
                                for (var y = 0; y <= storenum; y++) {
                                    var letter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + y);
                                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(locationset[y][2], locationset[y][3]);
                                    marker = createMarker(point, locationset[y][1], locationset[y][4], letter);
                                    markers[y] = marker;
                                    //Pass variables to the pop-up info windows
                                    create_store_variables(y);
                                    create_infowindow(marker, storeName);
                                }

                                //Creat the links that focus on the related marker
                                $("#" + settings.listDiv).empty();
                                $(markers).each(function (x, marker) {
                                    //Let's decleare the store variables again to make it easier to read the html below - there's probably a better way to do this
                                    var letter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + x);
                                    create_store_variables(x);
                                    //This needs to happen outside the loop or there will be a closure problem with creating the infowindows attached to the list click
                                    listClick(storeDistance, letter, marker, storeName);

                                });

                                function listClick(distance, letter, marker, name, address1, address2, city, state, zip, phone, web, hours1, hours2, hours3) {
                                    var distLength;
                                    if (distance <= 1) { distLength = "mile"; }
                                    else { distLength = "miles"; }

                                    var fullAddress = address1 + " " + address2 + ", " + city + ", " + state + " " + zip;
                                    var distLink = "<a href=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + origin + "&daddr=" + fullAddress + "\" target=\"_blank\">Directions<\/a>";

                                    $('<li />').html("<div class=\"list-label\">" + letter + "<\/div><div class=\"list-details\"><div class=\"list-content\"><div class=\"loc-name\">" + storeName + "<\/div><div class=\"loc-dist\">" + distance + " " + distLength + "<\/div><\/div><\/div>").click(function () {
                                        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
                                        var listLoc = "left";
                                        if (settings.bounceMarker == true) {
                                            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE)
                                            setTimeout(function () { marker.setAnimation(null); create_infowindow(marker, name, address1, address2, city, state, zip, phone, web, hours1, hours2, hours3, listLoc); }, 700);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            create_infowindow(marker, name, address1, address2, city, state, zip, phone, web, hours1, hours2, hours3, listLoc);
                                        }

                                    }).appendTo("#" + settings.listDiv);
                                }

                                //Add the list li background colors
                                $("#" + settings.listDiv + " li:even .list-details").css('background', "#" + settings.listColor1);
                                $("#" + settings.listDiv + " li:odd .list-details").css('background', "#" + settings.listColor2);

                                //Custom marker function - alphabetical
                                function createMarker(point, name, address, letter) {
                                    //Set up pin icon with the Google Charts API for all of our markers
                                    var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=" + letter + "|" + settings.pinColor + "|" + settings.pinTextColor,
                  new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
                  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                  new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
                                    var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
                  new google.maps.Size(40, 37),
                  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                  new google.maps.Point(12, 35));

                                    //Create the markers
                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: point,
                                        map: map,
                                        icon: pinImage,
                                        shadow: pinShadow,
                                        draggable: false
                                    });

                                    return marker;
                                }

                                //Let's save some space - creates and address line if the variable is set
                                function address_line(addressSegment) {
                                    var addressLine;

                                    if (addressSegment != "") {
                                        addressLine = "<div>" + addressSegment + "<\/div>";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        addressLine = "";
                                    }

                                    return addressLine;
                                }

                                //Infowindows
                                function create_infowindow(marker, name, address1, address2, city, state, zip, phone, web, hours1, hours2, hours3, location) {

                                    var formattedAddress = "<div class=\"loc-name\">" + name + "<\/div>" + address_line(address1) + address_line(address2) + city + ", " + state + " " + zip + address_line(hours1) + address_line(hours2) + address_line(hours3) + address_line(phone) + "<div><a href=\"http://" + web + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + web + "<\/a><\/div>";

                                    //Opens the infowindow when list item is clicked
                                    if (location == "left") {
                                        infowindow.setContent(formattedAddress);
                                        infowindow.open(marker.get(settings.mapDiv), marker);
                                    }
                                    //Opens the infowindow when the marker is clicked
                                    else {
                                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                                            infowindow.setContent(formattedAddress);
                                            infowindow.open(marker.get(settings.mapDiv), marker);
                                        })
                                    }
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all the map stuff is [aside the utility functions as listClick(), start from the 
//Create the map with jQuery line and ends just before  function listClick
if you comment out that section the map won't be created
just remember that ther's a map div that will still be visible [without mapo inside, but it will be still there, so think about commenting ut that HTML tag too

Comment: ive got it not to display the map and just left code in there, do you know what i would change just to display the 1 result closest?

Comment: all locations are in the property locationset, wich is ordered from the closest to the farer; beside the map ther's no other method to display data in this JS; maybe you should do something like $(midiv).html(here you build your html) just take locationset[0] as the closest point

Answer (score 3):

Use of geocoding without displaying map is against [Googles TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_g)